# How to hide UITabBar when going back in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have three viewControllers:

- FeedController (`UITabBar` is visible)
- PostController (`UITabBar` is hidden)
- UserController (`UITabBar` is visible

I do this with the following code, from FeedController to PostController:

```
let postVC = PostController()
postVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
pushViewController(postVC, animated: true)
postVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

Then, from PostVC to UserVC:

```
let userVC = UserController()
userVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
pushViewController(userVC, animated: true)
```

It works great. It shows the `UITabBar` everywhere except when navigating to a Post. However, the problem occurs when I go to a User Profile (UserController) from within a Post. It shows the `UITabBar` on the profile, as intended, but when I navigate back (using the back button in my `UINavigationController`) the `UITabBar` is still visible. I want it to be hidden again when I go back from the userVC to the postVC.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in your post viewController:

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   postVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```

That will call it when the view is about to disappear but not when it appears so it should hide when you go back.

Comment: That's incredible and does exactly what I need. Had been playing around with viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear but I was always working with the other viewController (e.g. changing postVC from userVC's willDisappear). This is great, thank you so much!

Comment: @PennyWise Great to hear! I found myself getting stuck in similar situations to yours many times, and the answer always comes when taking a break or doing something else! Think its easy to get caught in looking in the wrong place when your really focused, good luck!

Comment: I fear I was a bit too excited at first. When I implement this, all seems to work fine, however, if I go to another viewController from userVC, it hides the tabBar as well, while it should be shown again then, too. So I am currently looking into a way to only show it when I am sure the back button was tapped, so far, no luck.

Comment: @PennyWise is the back button a button you made, a navigation Bar back button or something else?

Comment: @PennyWise what first comes to mind is if for example its button you made, you could make a variable `var backButtonPressed = false` and in your button code set that to true and have your dismiss function there, and in viewWillDissapear you would just need `if backButtonPressed == true {` then hide the tabBar, and if they its not true, then go back without hiding it. Does that sound right?

Comment: Makes sense! I eventually fixed it by checking .isMovibgFromParent, if that is true, then the back button is pressed (it’s a navigationBackButton). So I am able to figure it out pretty okayish right now. Have a bit of difficulty with other tabs (I use a navigationController and a tabBarController), which can access the posts and users directly (e.g. a feed tab and a search tab can both navigate to users and posts). So if I switch between them it sometimes isn’t as expected, but I’ll figure that one out later I think. For now, the first tab works perfectly by checking isMovingFromParent!

Comment: @PennyWise Awesome! The best advice I could give is to write down or find a way to visualize all your possible segues, navigations etc and you might spot something that can help. Good luck!